# Google Docs Spreadsheet (app-script): Copying data between spreadsheets without duplicates

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a snippet of code I built to transfer a record from one spreadsheet to another in Google Docs for Spreadsheets (app-script).

```
function myFunction() {
    // Get Spreadsheets
    var source = SpreadsheetApp.openById("spreadsheetKeySource");
    var target = SpreadsheetApp.openById("spreadsheetKeyTarget");

    // Set Sheets
    var source_sheet = source.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    var target_sheet = target.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

    // Get target last row
    var last_row = target_sheet.getLastRow();

    // Set Ranges
    var source_range = source_sheet.getRange("A1:B1");
    var target_range = target_sheet.getRange("A"+(last_row+1)+":B"+(last_row+1));

    // Fetch values
    var values = source_range.getValues();

    // Save to spreadsheet
    target_range.setValues(values);
}
```

I need to know if it is possible to fetch the content from the source and loop through it and only add records that do not exist in the target.
Obviously, this function is inadequate for this purpose and I am hoping someone can push me in the right direction or even provide a code snippet as an example. I cannot find anything useful on Google or here so far... :(

Thanks for you help

**EDIT**

I was able to get this completed. The scope changed and now I had to fetch data from multiple spreadsheets with multiple sheets to fetch only emails and add them to a master email spreadsheet. Here is the code I created, hopefully it will help someone else too.

I actually made this script run when the masterSpreadsheet is opened and added a menu button to run this script.

```
/**
* Updates the master spreadsheet with the set source spreadsheets and pages
**/
function updateMasterSpreadsheet() {
  //  var sourceSpreadsheetsArray = new Array();
  var sourceSpreadsheetsObject = new Object;

  // Add Spreadsheet IDs and sheet names that need to be copied from
  sourceSpreadsheetsObject['sourceSpreadsheet1Key'] = new Array("Sheet1");
  sourceSpreadsheetsObject['sourceSpreadsheet2Key'] = new Array("Sheet1");

  // Open master spreadsheet
  var target = SpreadsheetApp.openById("masterSpreadsheetKey");

  // Open master sheet
  var target_sheet = target.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

  // Loop through all source spreadsheets
  for (var id in sourceSpreadsheetsObject) {
    // Open source spreadsheet
    var source = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);

    // Loop through and process each sheet
    for (var sheetID in sourceSpreadsheetsObject[id]) {
      // Open source spreadsheet sheet
      var source_sheet = source.getSheetByName(sourceSpreadsheetsObject[id][sheetID]);

      // Process sheet
      _updateMasterSpreadsheet(source_sheet, target_sheet);
    } // END - source sheets loop 

  } // END - source spreadsheets loop

  // Add last updated
  target_sheet.getRange("B1").setValue(new Date());
}

/**
* Performs the actual copy into the master spreadsheet
**/
function _updateMasterSpreadsheet(source_sheet, target_sheet) {
  // Get target last row
  var last_row = target_sheet.getLastRow();  

  // Get Source Range
  var source_range = source_sheet.getDataRange();

  // Fetch Source Values
  var source_data = source_range.getValues();  

  //Iterate over all cells, looking for non-empty ("") cells
  for (var row in source_data) {

    // check if empty
    if (source_data[row][0]!= "") {
      // Fetch data in the sheet (do this in the loop to ensure that we check all newly added items)
      var target_range = target_sheet.getDataRange();
      var target_data = target_range.getValues();  

      // Set flags
      var found = false;
      var stop = false;

      // Process loop
      while(found == false && stop == false) {
        // Check for duplicates
        for (var tmpRow in target_data) {
          if (source_data[row][0] == target_data[tmpRow][0]) {
            found = true;
            break;
          }
        }

        // If no duplicate, add to sheet
        if (!found) {
          last_row++;
          target_sheet.getRange("A"+last_row).setValue(source_data[row][0]);
        }

        // Prevent infinite loop
        stop = true;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This tutorial from the Google Apps Script documentation should help you:

[Tutorial: Removing Duplicate Rows in a Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/removing_duplicates)

There is also a script named "Remove duplicates" in the Apps Script Gallery

Comment: Thanks, I actually figured this out last night and luckily my duplicate check is very similar to this example.

Answer (score 0):

One of our more experience people (which is plenty) may have a different take on it, but I'd guess you'd have to compare the two line-by-line.  That would work only assuming the contents haven't been manually changed in either sheet.

What is it you're attempting to do? If you describe your use case, then we may be able to provide other thoughts...

Comment: A simple project got more complicated but luckily I was able to figure this out and the project is complete. I had to move data between multiple spreadsheets and multiple sheets into a master spreadsheet. The purpose is to fetch emails (all stored in different locations in each sheet) to the master spreadsheet which is just a list of emails, ensuring there are no duplicates.